# Finding $k - E(v | v \leq k)$ when the pdf is $f(v)=\frac{1}{2}\exp^{-|v|}$, and $k\geq0$

Tags: probability, integration

The solution is supposed to be $\frac{1+k}{1-2e^k}$

I tried using the fact that $k-\frac{\int_{a}^{k}uf(u)du}{F(k)}=\frac{\int_{a}^{k}F(u)du}{F(k)}$

Any ideas of where I am going wrong? I tried splitting the integral at 0 but I kept getting an answer of 1 regardless. Even though the answer should only be one if k<0.

Comment: What does $E(v \le k) $ mean?

Comment: There was previously an error. I meant to write the expectation of v given tht v less than or equal to k.

Comment: I suspect you have an error in your computation. As far as I can tell, $E[v | v \le k ] = { \int_{-\infty}^k v f(v) dv \over \int_{-\infty}^k f(v) dv } = { -1 + 1- e^{-k} (k+1) \over 1+ 1-e^{-k}} = { k+1 \over 1-2 e^k}$.

Comment: Where did you get the fraction after your first equal sign from? It is different than the one I calculated which I have written above.

Comment: I evaluated the integrals...

Comment: So you are saying that the final solution is missing the k term as it is just $E[v|v \leq k]$ and it didn't include $k-E[v|v \leq k]$?

Comment: Yes, but just evaluate the integral yourself. It is not particularly difficult or tedious.

Comment: Great, I was previously evaluating $\frac{\int^k_aF(u)du}{F(k)}$ instead which must have been why I was not able to see the connection that k was missing from the final solution.